# How to upload twilio programmable video recording to S3 without using enterprise edition?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I am trying to upload video recordings of twilio to S3 but I found out its an enterprise feature. What are the other ways that it can be done ? I am using nodejs and react using twilio sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to repurpose the code in this blog for that purpose.

Encrypting and Storing Twilio Flex Recordings Off-site
https://www.twilio.com/blog/encrypt-store-twilio-flex-recordings-site